# Ruby object undefined method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, attr-accessor

I had this:

```
class ProposalsController < ApplicationController
  def forkIt 

     return "FFFFFUUUU"
  end
end
```

But when I tried to access the method (so I can gave my FFFFUUUU RAGE) it told me that such method was undefined.

Now, I read somewhere that i needed to make it accessible, so this came

```
class ProposalsController < ApplicationController
   attr_accessor :forkIt
   def forkIt 
      return "FFFFFUUUU"
   end
end
```

This is the ruby console extract

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > @proposal = Proposal.find(4)
 => #<Proposal id: 4, title: "asda", description: "fdsfds", owner: 1, parent_id: nil, created_at: "2011-08-12 21:28:39", updated_at: "2011-08-12 21:28:39"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > @proposal.forkIt
NoMethodError: undefined method `forkIt' for #<Proposal:0x9b11030>
```

But still nothing... help this Ruby noob. thanks.

Comment: Show us how you are calling it.

Comment: How are you trying to call/access the method? And `attr_accessor` is for instance variables, not methods. By default all methods in Ruby are public, unless you mark them otherwise.

Comment: Also, you don't need the 'return'. The last line will automatically be returned.

Comment: Thanks, now I've added the console extract.

Comment: Ruby usually uses `snake_case` for method names, not `camelCase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined your `forkIt` method on on your **controller**, `ProposalsController`, but you're **calling** it on the model, `Proposal`.

You need to move `forkIt` to the model class.

`@proposal = Proposal.find(4)` makes `@propsal` an instance of the `Proposal` class, not the `ProposalControllers` class.